# Defining modules in UI5

Tags: requirejs, sapui5

I am trying to keep my code separated in modules. When I defined my first module I extended sap.ui.base.Object and it worked. My question is: Is it a must to extend sap.ui.base.Object when defining my own module? According to the [API documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.define) I tried following example:

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {

    // create a new class
    var SomeClass = function();

    // add methods to its prototype
    SomeClass.prototype.foo = function() {
        return "Foo";
    }

    // return the class as module value
    return SomeClass;
});
```

I required this module inside my Component.js as dependency like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
"path/to/SomeClass"
], function (SomeClass) {
  "use strict";
//var test = new SomeClass();
```

I always receive a syntax error:

```
failed to load '[...]/Component.js' from ./Component.js: Error: failed to load '[...]/module/SomeClass.js' from ./module/Service.js: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: You have a semicolon in the wrong place. Could you post the entire code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake - missing curly brackets in the docs.
var someclass = function() {} ;

Answer (score 0):

We group code in modules like this for example:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("our.namespace.iscool.util.Navigation");
our.namespace.iscool.util.Navigation = {
    to: function (pageId, context) {
        // code here
    }
    // etc.
}
```

and call the function of the module like this in a controller

```
jQuery.sap.require("our.namespace.iscool.util.Navigation");
sap.ui.controller("our.namespace.iscool.Detail", {
    // somewhere in this file comes this
    handleNavButtonPress: function (evt) {
    our.namespace.iscool.util.Navigation.navBackToMaster(
       evt.getSource().getBindingContext()
    );
},
}
```